# Run app in system/priv-app folder on not rooted real device while developing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions, phone-state-listener

Is there any solution to run app in system/priv-app folder on not rooted real device to grant system apps permissions like `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` while developing?

I'm going to disconnect incoming calls programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that there is no way to run app in system/priv-app folder on not rooted real devices to grant system apps. It's only possible on rooted devices.